# How do I configure lightdm to work with XDMCP?

Tags: lightdm, xdmcp

Does anyone have a set up to make XDMCP work with LightDM on 11.10. Using XDMCP+GDM was easy as pie, worked great. After the upgrade to 11.10 with the switch to LightDM I can't figure out how to get it to work. Where is the documentation that explains the custom lightdm.conf file?

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 24):

To enable the XDMCP server in LightDM edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and add the following section:

```
[XDMCPServer]
enabled=true
```

Then restart LightDM with `sudo restart lightdm` from a text console (logout from any graphical sessions first).

You can set the XDM-AUTHENTICATION-1 key by setting key=value (value is in the same format as is used in the X -cookie option).  If the key is not set then no authentication is used.

You can change the UDP/IP port by setting port=1234.

All the available LightDM settings are shown in the example configuration in `/usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.

Comment: In 12.04 the sample conf file is in /usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz